# C++ error in gcc and sucess VS

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++, gcc

The code below not compile in gcc 4.7, but compile in VS(9, 10, 11) also follows the gcc output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void M() = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    inline B& operator<<(A &value)
    {
        value.M();
        return *this;
    }
};

class C: public A
{
public:
    virtual void M()
    {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;

    b << c;   //line not erro
    b << C(); //Line with error

    return 0;
}
```

gcc log

> $g++ main.cpp -o test main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   main.cpp:36:12: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'b << C()'
>   main.cpp:36:12: note: candidates are: main.cpp:14:15: note: B&
>   B::operator<<(A&) main.cpp:14:15: note: no known conversion for
>   argument 1 from 'C' to 'A&'

Comment: You should listen to the warnings MSVC is throwing at you. At some point it is telling you that "copying temporary to a l-value reference is a non-standard behavior" (or something similar)...

Answer (score 7):

C++ does not allow you to bind a non-const reference to a temporary like you are attempting to do here:

```
b << C();
//   ^^^^ temporary
```

VS allows you to do this as an "extension", but it is non-standard and therefore non-portable, as you have discovered.

What you need is a `const` reference in the relevant operator:

```
inline B& operator<<(const A& value)
//                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: I understood then that is not part of **C++ standard**, thank you juanchopanza.

Answer (score 1):

One way of sorting it out is using C++11 rvalue binding feature.

```
B& operator<<(A&& value)
{ ... }
```

as an overload.